# Block Queue delivery on RabbitMQ

Tags: php, python, rabbitmq

I'm looking for a way to block message delivery for a moment and reactivate it without loosing the messages.

The case is when we need to migrate consumers, I don't want messsages to be delivered for like 10 minutes. I want to block queue delivery and then reactivate it.

Is there a way to do this? In Python or in PHP?

EDIT:

With this process I don't want to get consumers disconnected. I want it like putting the queue on hold, no message delivered to current consumers and then "reactivate it".

Comment: The queues can store the messages, if the queue has not consumers. unless you are using exclusive and autodelete queues. What kind of the queues are you using ?

Comment: "classic" queue i guess, no options are set except of prefetch on the consumers

Comment: I've not played with it myself but a solution might be the [delayed message exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/) plugin.

Comment: "I" is always uppercase in English. [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) are the most important trivial spelling problems and their solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Though you already might have solved the problem:
You could use 2 Queues instead of one.

*produce -> Q1 -> Direct Exchange -> Q2 -> consume*

Then you can dynamically delete the binding (API call "unbind") between the Exchange and the Q2. Then Q2 drains empty and Msg queue in Q1 until you bind it again after your maintenance.

I wish there was something like "Pause Queue for x-Minutes" to implement a simple retry mechanism.